# How do I execute a CQL statement inside a user-defined function?

Tags: sql, cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I want to trigger the Cassandra query when the Java/JavaScript code if statement satisfied? For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1 (val1 int, val2int)
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    RETURN int
    LANGUAGE java
    AS $$
       int res = 0;
       if (val1 == 10) {
        some cassandra query
       } else {
        some cassandra query
       }
       return res;
    $$;
```

In the example, I want to insert some Cassandra operation, like update, insert etc. How could I do that?

Thanks for your help and time.

I want to convert the sql procedure to cql function. so, the result expecting is to give some idea to simulate the sql procedure could combo business logical code and sql query in Cassandra Function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not a supported feature and I'm not aware of any workarounds. Cheers!